# How to disable sub-sampling when saving jpg image using PHP GD library?

Tags: php, image-processing, subsampling

I noticed that each time I save a jpg file in PHP, it is saved with sub-sampling. How to remove that? I'm using GD library.

Answer (score 0):

I believe newer versions of `libgd` disable chroma-subsampling if you set the quality to 90 or higher.

Failing that, you could consider using **PHP Imagick** and disabling chroma sub-sampling with:

```
$img->setSamplingFactors(array('1x1', '1x1', '1x1'));
```